# What does this sentence mean, especially {subject to}

Tags: meaning

"Subject to you meeting any outstanding non-academic conditions."

Can someone rewrite this sentence so that I can better understand, especially the usage of the word subject in this case.

Comment: Subject as an adjective, definition 2 https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subject#Adjective

Comment: So should I consider that it means "conditional upon"? Or still, I am confused with what is subject to what.

Comment: If you say *A is **subject** to B* you mean A *depends* on B. It's a straightforward metaphoric extension from the *under the rule or control of someone or something* sense that would be literally applied to peasants whose wellbeing was *subject to the whim of the king* (that's why they were his *subjects*). In your case it's just a formal long-winded way of saying ***IF [you meet the conditions]*** (it's an unlikely construction in natural conversation).

Answer (score 2):

Subject to you meeting any outstanding non-academic conditions.

Means

> If you take care of your non-academic obligations (if you have any).

*Subject* means *dependent on:*

Adj
2.dependent or conditional upon.
"the proposed merger is subject to the approval of the shareholders"
--https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=define+subject&gfe_rd=cr&ei=P7q5V5eRBs2A2QTPmYyIBQ

Your sentence might mean that you can get your degree if you have paid your tuition, etc.